# Custom Availability not working anywmore with new template [magento 1.9]

Tags: magento-1.9, stock-status

When I set up a product in **stock "-1"** the availability is not displayed, the product always displays **"In Stock"**.

Is it possible to add a condition for products in stock "-1" to display the **"Availability"** custom message set in product ? (and keep In Stock/Out of Stock)

[image: stock setup]

[image: availability]

> file:
>   /app/design/frontend/default/themeXXXX/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
            <?php if ($_product->getTypeId() == "simple"): ?>
                <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
                    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span style="color:#74b436"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method with an atribute works

```
            <?php if ($_product->getTypeId() == "simple"): ?>
                <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
                    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                        <?php $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product->getId()); ?>
                        <?php if($stock->getQty()==-1): ?>
                            <?php if($_product->getDispo()) : ?>
                                <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span style='color: #FF0000;'><?php echo $_product->getDispo(); ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                                <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span style="color:#74b436"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>    
                        <?php endif; ?>
                   <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's not tested but it should work

```
<?php if ($_product->getTypeId() == "simple"): ?>
    <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable() || $_product->getQty() == "-1" ): ?>
            <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span style="color:#74b436"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Update:

```
<?php if ($_product->getTypeId() == "simple"): ?>
    <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable() || $_product->getQty() == "-1" ): ?>
            <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span style="color:#74b436"><?php echo $_product->getAvailability(); ?></span></p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey, I try nothing change always "In stock"

Comment: What always "In stock" ? I don't understand what you want to do !

Comment: With old template when i put product "In stock" & stock "-1" &  "Availability"  message like "Available within 2-3 days" it was displayed on the product page instead of "in stock" , now it does not take into account the message that is given in the field "Availability"

Comment: Look my update...

Comment: Create custom product attribute where you can set available or not ( 1 or 0 ). And on the phtml page just load product by id and check this attribute.

Comment: I have look code from old template, is custom. He use your method. Thanks !  I add the code in reply